# Include<Eigen/Dense> lead to fatal error: 'Eigen/Dense' file not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, include, eigen, vscode-debugger

I am faced with the problem that VSCode does not see Eigen
when I run the program in the debug mode, I get the following error

```
fatal error: 'eigen/Eigen/Dense' file not found
```

However, I have added the appropriate paths to task.json

```
"args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "-std=c++20",
            "-I /Users/%USERNAME%/C++Projects/dependencies/eigen/",
        ],
```

and to c_cpp_properties.json also

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/Users/%USERNAME%/C++Projects/dependencies/eigen/"
```

And of course when I compile directly through the terminal using

```
g++ filename.cpp -std=c++20 -I /Users/%USERNAME%/C++Projects/dependencies/eigen/ -o outputfile
```

Everything is going well

Well, does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Lol
Guys I just made a space between the "-I" and the "/Users/..." in the task.json

Comment: Good to see you solved the problem.  You can put that as an answer (and accept it), or delete (or close) the question as being a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol
Guys I just made a space between the "-I" and the "/Users/..." in the task.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).